# When We switch to anther account , which broadcast should we receive

Tags: android

When Android system started up , we could using android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED to get this Event . but which broadcast should we receive when we switch to another account (Android Pad) . I would be so glad if someone would help ^ ^

Comment: the question is intresting. what have you tried so far?

Comment: ACTION_USER_SWITCH can do